# 2 java scripts in one single html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made 2 diferent javascripts (dreamweaver cs6)

**1 is for a nav bar** and the other **one is for a verticalscrolling**

My question is how to make the two js working at the same time.

Comment: Just import both into your HTML document.

Comment: by including both js in the same file

Comment: You can include them both with two separate `<script src=""></script>` tags, or just put them inline. What have you tried and/or what is breaking?

Comment: We'll need more information than this. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Could you put more detailed information in your question and make it clearer?

Comment: it is not working, i already try before ask...

Comment: @DiogoFilipeCardoso: What is not working?  What did you try?  In what way is it not working?  Do you get an error message?  What indication do you have that there is a problem?  Right now your question is simply "My code doesn't work, what's wrong?"  We can't possibly answer that without seeing relevant parts of your code along with a description of the problem.

Comment: A have 2 scripts, 1 is for verticall scrolling, and the other one is for a nav bar. the vertical scrolling script is working fine, but the nav bar is not working, but if I delete the verticalscroling it starts to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two scripts will work at the same time, just import them into the document.